# Bad Topology problem

Tags: topology

Hope you and your families are ok in that moments, and i hope de will pass that soon.

I have a topology problem, the result is a problem on subdision.

I have that object, when i apply the subsdivision surface, the circle goes to a "non circle".
I don't know where i have to cut the mesh to break the loop that distorts that circle.

Thank you.

[image]

---

Thank you very much batFINGER and Robin Betts,

in fact tihs is the vest topology lesseon i have never recieved, that let me understand better the workflow for a good topology.

I have one more question, dou you know why the external part is not beieng correctly subdivided?

[image]

Moltes gràcies!

Comment: The bigger up / down hole has an "outset" ring around the hole, would add similar.

Comment: Agreed. The distortion is caused by uneven sizes in the immediately surrounding faces, Catmull-Clark is pulling further into the larger faces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this. But depends what you want to do next [image]

Comment: Thank you very much Fowl, batFINGER and Robin Betts,

in fact tihs is the vest topology lesseon i have never recieved, that let me understand better the workflow for a good topology.

I have one more question, dou you know why the external part is not beieng correctly subdivided?

Comment: isnt that just not-smoothed? right click on the object and ->shade smooth.